# I don't know what my teacher is asking of me. Have I understood the assignment correctly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have made the assignment but I am still confused if I have clearly understood what my teacher ask of me. Can I get your take on this thing?

I have tried with two arrays, for-loop and when I use a button connected with a function, it seems to be working. But the question is, if it is correct. My school assignment is in Swedish, so that is why a few words are that language.

This is the assignment question:

Morgan, a high school teacher, needs a register to keep track of their students' grades. Suppose you have two arrays, one with a name and one with a rating. For example: namn = ["Klara", "Andrea", "Emil", "Sarah", "Alicia", "Victor", "Thomas", "Robert"] with the grades: betyg = ["A", "B" , "C", "A", "D", "C", "E", "E"]. Then do a function (getGrade) that searches for a name and returns the grade (first matching name is enough). Then do a page that tests and demonstrates your new feature (automatically when the page is loaded or via a button press). The array names and ratings can be global variables or, slightly nicer, local variables sent as input to the functions.

```html
<body>

  <input type="button" value="Click to get Student Name and Grade" onclick="getGrade()">
  <div id="student1"></div>
  <div id="student2"></div>
  <div id="student3"></div>
  <div id="student4"></div>
  <div id="student5"></div>
  <div id="student6"></div>
  <div id="student7"></div>
  <div id="student8"></div>


  <script>
    var namn = ["Klara", "Andrea", "Emil", "Sarah", "Alicia", "Victor", "Thomas", "Robert"];

    var betyg = ["A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "C", "E", "E"];

    function getGrade() {

      for (var i = 0; i < namn.length; i++) {
        if (namn[i] == namn[0]) {
          document.getElementById("student1").innerHTML += namn[i] + "<br/> Betyg: " + betyg[i];
        } else if (namn[i] == namn[1]) {
          document.getElementById("student2").innerHTML += namn[i] + "<br/> Betyg: " + betyg[i];;
        } else if (namn[i] == namn[2]) {
          document.getElementById("student3").innerHTML += namn[i] + "<br/> Betyg: " + betyg[i];;
        } else if (namn[i] == namn[3]) {
          document.getElementById("student4").innerHTML += namn[i] + "<br/> Betyg: " + betyg[i];;
        } else if (namn[i] == namn[4]) {
          document.getElementById("student5").innerHTML += namn[i] + "<br/> Betyg: " + betyg[i];;
        } else if (namn[i] == namn[5]) {
          document.getElementById("student6").innerHTML += namn[i] + "<br/> Betyg: " + betyg[i];;
        } else if (namn[i] == namn[6]) {
          document.getElementById("student7").innerHTML += namn[i] + "<br/> Betyg: " + betyg[i];;
        } else {
          document.getElementById("student8").innerHTML += namn[i] + "<br/> Betyg: " + betyg[i];;
        }

      }
    }
  </script>
```

Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Does a name at one index in one array mean that that name got the grade at the same index in the other array?

Comment: _"...that **searches** for a name and **returns** the grade..."_ - At the moment you're just printing all names and their grades in the order of the `namn` array.

Comment: Please provide original task text.

Comment: Can't you ask your teacher?

Comment: Morgan, som är högstadielärare, behöver ett register för att hålla ordning på sina elevers betyg. Antag att du har två arrayer, en med namn och en med betyg. Exempelvis: namn = ["Klara", "Andrea", "Emil", "Sarah", "Alicia", "Victor", "Thomas", "Robert"] med betygen: betyg = ["A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "C", "E", "E"]. Gör därefter en funktion (getGrade) som söker efter ett namn och returnerar betyget (första matchande namnet räcker). Gör därefter en sida som testar och demonstrerar din nya funktion (automatiskt när sidan laddas eller via en knapptryckning).

Comment: Arrayerna namn och betyg kan vara globala variabler eller, lite snyggare, lokala variabler som skickas som indata till funktionerna.

Comment: No, not at this point because he is not available until the autumn again.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the assignment requires you to get the grade of X (name).

`getGrade` should return the grade of `X`.

`X` can be from an `input text` or something else.

`getGrade` also should accept a parameter.

Basically,

```
var grade = getGrade('Klara');

function getGrade(name) {
   var grade = ...
   return grade;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the whole question and why it is provided in two separate arrays.
And I do not know what kind of tools you can use (since this is an assignment), but in nutshell you need something like this

```
var namn = ['Klara', 'Andrea', 'Emil', 'Sarah', 'Alicia', 'Victor', 'Thomas', 'Robert'];

var betyg = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'E'];
var dict = {};
for (var i = 0; i < namn.length; i++) {
  dict[namn[i].toLowerCase()] = betyg[i];
}

function getGrade(name) {
  return dict[name.toLowerCase()] || undefined;
}
var $app = document.body;
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'text';
var button = document.createElement('button');
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
button.innerText = 'Get Grade';
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
var grade = getGrade(input.value)
  if (grade) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = input.value + ' grade is: ' + grade;
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
});

$app.appendChild(input);
$app.appendChild(button);
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(ul);
$app.appendChild(div);
```

I have not done so many refactors (like creating an element or other things);

If grade of student is index-wise (could not find any better word) with name array, first you can create an Object (key value pairs) and then simply get the grade by passing the name of the student. 
The rest is just putting result on HTML.

I add also an input to get the name and by clicking on button, the list is generated.

If you want to refactor your solution you can use something this:

```
var namn = ["Klara", "Andrea", "Emil", "Sarah", "Alicia", "Victor", "Thomas", "Robert"];

var betyg = ["A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "C", "E", "E"];

function getGrade() {
    for (var i=1; i<=namn.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById('student' + i ).innerText = namn[i-1] + ' Betyg' + betyg[i-1]
    }
}
```